# How can I implement facebook and google+ login using ionic framework for hybrid mobile development?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic framework. I have to implement login sign-up feature with Facebook and google+ in my hybrid mobile app. How can add this login & sign-up feature? Does it allows me to login via fb or google+ inside a hybrid mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to build an app implementing Facebook's OAuth, it's pretty straightforward if you're willing to use `ngCordova`

Add in the ngcordova library to your ionic project.

```
bower install ngCordova
```

Include `ngCordova` to your `index.html` file before `cordova.js`

Make sure you inject `ngCordova` to your angular module (usually in `app.js`)

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCordova'])
```

To use multiple OAuth providers supported by `ngCordova`, you need to get cordova's inappbrowser plugin, add that into the mix

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

To use it in controllers check out http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

**Note:** The installation documented in ngCordova's oauth plugin page usually doesn't works, and when using the app in an emulator or a device it returns **"Could not find InAppBrowser plugin"** for every provider.

The workaround is pretty simple indeed, open up `ng-cordova.js` residing in your `www/lib/ngCordova/dist` directory and with a quick **find and replace**

**Find:**

```
cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty("org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser") === true
```

**Replace With:**

```
cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty("cordova-plugin-inappbrowser") === true || cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty("org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser") === true`
```

That should give you a headstart with the development process, the more you know!

Comment: Means it do not require to use any APP_ID to be created in facebook developer account?

Comment: You do, check out the ngCordova documentation I linked